# Declaring array-spec in the dimension attr-spec and in entity-decl at the same time

Tags: arrays, fortran, language-lawyer, gfortran, intel-fortran

This code compiles in gfortran, Intel Fortran and Solaris Studio

```
  real, dimension(:) :: A(2)
  print *, size(A)
end
```

The result is 2.

However, when another *array-spec* is attempted in a dimension statement

```
  dimension A(1)
  real :: A(2)
  print *, size(A)
end
```

all three compilers issue an error that the dimension attribute was given twice.

Is the first code standard conforming and what exactly does the standard (as recent as possible) says about this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard says:

- a array specification on an entity in a type declaration statement overrides any DIMENSION(...) attribute specification *in that same statement* (F2018 8.2p2), when determining what the statement specifies as the attribute for the entity.
- an attribute may not be specified twice (F2018 C815).

The first program is conforming, with the behaviour observed as per the standard; the second is not, given C815.

These rules have applied since Fortran 90.  The equivalent of C815 is in F77 as well, F66 is characteristically ambiguous...

Comment: The syntax used by the OP seems legit: `real,dimension(:) :: A(2)`. But I'm surprised that `real,dimension(whatever,whatever,whatever...) :: A(2)` even compiles. I wonder if you could offer some insight for when and why this behavior might be ok, or useful?

Comment: @MattP At least it does complain when whatever is not declared and implicit none is specified.

Comment: However, `real, dimension(1000.,1000.,1000.,1000.) :: A(2)` is allowed by Intel and gfortran and rejected by Oracle. I do not know which is correct.

Comment: @VladimirF, `real, dimension(1000.,1000.,1000.,1000.) :: A(2)` is not a valid Fortran declaration statement.  The array bounds in the attribute specification must be valid specification expressions even if they are later overridden.

Comment: @francescalus Actually, gfortran v. 6 and later does reject it as well.

Comment: I expect (I do not know) the reason for the Fortran 90 behaviour for the dimension attribute in a type declaration statement (and later, the codimension attribute) is consistency with existing language features - having the entity specific attribute override the statement general attribute is how things worked with type declaration statements in Fortran 77.